# Split a graph on order to solve min cut max flow algorithm in parallel

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I'm working with very big graph (millions of nodes) that have this structure:
[image: Graph]

I'd like to solve the maximum flow/minimum cut problem in parallel by splitting the graph into multiple parts in order to use more than one CPU core.
I know that there are [approaches](https://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1567612&fileOId=1580403) to do so but I can' understand well how to use them in my graph.
Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The picture suggest that all the edge capacities are equal to $1.0$, is this correct, or that's just an example?

Comment: @dtldarek no, it is just an example, edges weights are not predictable...